# Dynamically alter django model's field return value

Tags: django

Let's say I have a setup similar to this:

```
class UnitsOfMeasure(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    precision = models.PositiveIntegerField()

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    uom = models.ForeignKey(UnitsOfMeasure)
    qty_available = models.DecimalField(max_tigits=10, decimal_places=10)
```

Now lets say we have a product related to Units of measure instance with precision = 2.
How can I do that qty_available would return 5.50 instead of 5.5000000000?

I know I can use property decorator, but this does not solve my problem, since I want to use qty_available as a field in forms.

Custom Field type? How can I pass and access related model instance then??

Your ideas are very appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Override the `__init__` method of your model field and set the `max_digits` based on the related unit of measure.

```
class ProductForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ProductForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['qty_available'] = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=self.instance.uom.precision)
    class Meta:
        model = Product
```

Comment: This solves the problem only in ModelForm. How about displaying a value on templates? Then I need custom template filter... What if I want to have different forms with this field? Than I have to repeat this code over and over again... sounds like not very DRY...

Comment: You can use a property or a template tag for presentation. If you need multiple forms then you should be able to use inheritance to reductive duplicated code. This might not be as DRY as you like, and you may be able to do something cleverer with a custom field, but I'm not sure it will be as simple and easy to understand.

Answer (score 0):

If it's just a presentation problem, you can use a `simple_tag` in your templates:

```
@register.simple_tag
def format_qty_available(product):
    return product.qty_available.quantize(Decimal(10) ** -product.uom.precision)
```

Comment: This wont work for a form field. If this were an approach, you are better off creating a model property, than a template tag

Comment: "Fat" models, you are right. Thanks. But as you said, I missed the point of the question anyway.